# What are Angular Templates relative to?

Tags: angularjs, templates

I am using Angular's ui.bootstrap. I have a structure that looks like the following. I have another folder of the ui-bootstrap templates that I am having trouble figuring out where to place in order for ui-bootstrap to see it because I'm consistently getting the error "[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template"

```
app
--> template
----> index.html
----> ...
--> js
----> modules.js
----> ...
--> lib
----> angular
------> ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js
------> angular.js
```

EDIT: I see here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/IFn3L6Tz4oc that I am not supposed to include the template/* folder that it's in the ui-bootstrap project. It's already in the ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js file starting on line 3351. However, my app is not seeing this even though it's seeing the typeahead module.

EDIT: Ok, this was my silliness. I was including a $templateCache.removeAll() at the bottom of my module from some previous work. Getting rid of that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions - those templates are relative to the root of your web application on the web server OR the value defined in the `base` tag.

Having said the above you are likely including wrong files from the angular-ui/bootstrap as normally you would use a file with templates bundled together (something like `ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].js`. From your included file structure it *looks* like you including the right file so just make sure that you include one and only one file from the distribution. More info here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files

The only valid reason to actually include template files is when you want to override default templates. But even in this case you should bundle directive templates with your java script code as loading many small templates is hurting performance. More info on overriding templates can be found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#customize-templates

Hopefully the above will help to solve your immediate issue, if not post a reproduce scenario using http://plnkr.co/